# OpenMDAO v/s modeFrontier comparisons for optimization capabilities and application scaling

Tags: optimization, openmdao

I realize that this might not be the best platform to ask this, but I think this would be best unbiased one to put my question in.

How would you compare OpenMDAO v/s modeFrontier with regards to there optimization capabilities and application scaling and overall software development? Which one would you pick and why?

If you know of any resources or link do provide.

Comment: I haven't used modeFrontier so I can't compare directly. In my experience, the difference between OpenMDAO and other "linking" tools like iSight and ModelCenter is that those tools pass inputs/outputs across different tools but not derivatives.  OpenMDAO is primarily built to enable the passing of derivative information across these systems so we can efficiently employ gradient based optimization across the entire combined model. OpenMDAO _can_ be used to link tools with finite differencing if they want, since not all existing tools provide access to derivatives/residuals.

Answer (score 2):

The most fundamental technical difference is OpenMDAO can pass data + derivative information between components. This means that if you want to use gradient based optimization and have access to at least some tools that provide derivative information, OpenMDAO will have far more effective overall capabilities. This is especially important when doing optimization with high-cost analysis tools (e.g. partial differential equation solvers --- CFD, FEA). In those situations making use of derivatives offers between a [100x and 10000x speedup](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=7a879f0ac23839f2be7df5c71d055887d2489497).

One other difference is that OpenMDAO is designed to run natively on a distributed memory compute cluster. Industrial frameworks can submit jobs to remote clusters and query for the results, but OpenMDAO itself can run on the cluster and has a direct and internal MPI based distributed memory capability. This is critical to it being able to efficiently handle derivatives of those expensive PDE solvers. To the best of my knowledge, OpenMDAO is unique in this regard. This is a low level technical detail that most users never need to directly understand, but the consequence is that if you want to do any kind of high fidelity coupled optimziations (aero-structural, aero-propulsive, aero-thermal) with more than one PDE solver in the loop then OpenMDAO's architecture is going to be by far the most effective.

However, OpenMDAO does not offer a GUI. It does not have the same level of data tracking and visualization tools. Also, I know that mode-frontier offers the ability to split a single model up across multiple computers distributed across an organization. Mode Frontier, along with other tools like ModelCenter and Isight, all offer this kind of smooth user experience and code-free interaction that many find valuable.

Honestly, I'm not sure a direct comparison is really warranted. I think if you have an organization that invests in a commercial integration tool like Mode Fronteir, then you can still use OpenMDAO to create tightly coupled integrated optimizations which you can then include as boxes inside your overall integration framework.

You certainly can use OpenMDAO as a complete integration framework, and it has some advantages in that area related to derivatives and execution in distributed memory environments. But you don't have to, and it certainly does not have to be an exclusive decision.